# Iphone sdk - Generate local HTML

Tags: iphone, html, sdk, local, textfield

I need your help. How can I make it on SDK?

1) receive input from the user (TextField)
2) generate or write it to a html local file with text received of Textfield ( Html local )

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming textField is a valid UITextField instance, with the user's input typed inside):

```
NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"user.html"];
[textField.text writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```